# Why past tense(emerged) used here?

Tags: tense

By the time the CIA assessment finally emerged it was an anticlimax, its conclusions already known: America believes Muhammad bin Salman, the kingdom’s crown prince and de facto ruler, approved the operation to capture or kill Mr Khashoggi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what other tense you might expect: it is an event which took place in the past and is complete.

If it were in a main clause, you could use the perfect and say *The CIA assessment **has** finally emerged*, if you wished to relate it to the present. (You could also use the simple past, if it was not important or relevant to relate it to the present),

But *by the time* locates the event in at a specific time (in this case, in the past) with no relevance to the present, so it would not be normal to use a perfect construction within that clause.

Comment: So far as I can see, if we *do* use Simple Present tense after ***by the time***, we're actually always referring to ***something that will happen in the future*** (not something that's *currently* happening). So Present Perfect seems to be the *only* way to indicate that "[by] the time" referred to is in fact ***now***.

Comment: Yes indeed, as follows from the fact that the so-called present is in fact non-past.  If you use a present perfect inside _by the time_ it will have future (perfect) meaning: _By the time I've seen him, it'll be too late_.

Comment: John Lawler tells me *English only has two tenses (Present, and "not-Present").* Does your "the so-called present is in fact non-past" imply *English only has two tenses (Past, and "not-Past")?*

Comment: Does he really, @FumbleFingers? I am astonished. Where? While I worked out for myself that there is no such thing as a future tense in English, I thought it was from John Lawler that I'd got the clarity of past vs non-past being the only two tenses.

Comment: It was several years ago. We seem to agree we both got "only two tenses" from John, and I'm sure that would always have been a more "accessible" concept to you than to me, so perhaps I'm misremembering (or I misunderstood). Anyway, whichever of Past and Present you choose for the "named" one of the "only two", the *typical* "non-that-choice" alternative will in fact be the other one. And temporally speaking there's only really Past, Present, Future, so the thing it mostly implies either way round is "English doesn't have a ***Future*** Tense*.